# при выполнении программы кликера она зависает

Tags: python, tkinter, pyautogui

Я написал автокликер, при нажатии функции "запустить автокликер" программа просто зависает. Поставил максимальную задержку кликера, все равно.

```
from tkinter import *
import pyautogui as pg
import keyboard
import time
import sys


Butik = ''

def click():
    time.sleep(1)
    pg.click()


def main():
    global btn3
    global Buton
    stop_word = Buton
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed(stop_word):
           break
        click()


def clicked():
   global Butik
   res = txt.get
   Butik = res
   btn.configure(text="Назначено!")


def stop():
   sys.exit()

window = Tk()
window.title("AutoClicker")
window.geometry('250x250')
lbl = Label(window, text = "Кликер!", font=("Times new Roman", 15))
lbl.grid(padx=50, pady=10)
lbl2 = Label(window, text = "Назначь кнопку остановки кликера", font=("Times, 10"))
lbl2.grid(padx=10, pady=10)
txt = Entry(window, width=10)
txt.grid(padx=10, pady=1)
btn = Button(window, text="Назначить", command=clicked)
btn.grid(column=0, row=3)
btn2 = Button(window, text="Запустить кликер!", command=main)
btn2.grid(column=0, pady=30)
btn3 = Button(window, text = "Остановить", command=stop)
btn3.grid(column=0, row=5)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: В ткинтер тоже есть цикл while - основной цикл приложения, так никто из них  и не победил.

Comment: все заработало?

Comment: Если нет, то убери галочку

Comment: не заработало, все так же зависает при авто клике

Answer (score 3):

Возможно, одной из причин, по которой твоя программа может зависать при запуске автокликера, является то, что цикл `while True` в функции `main()` выполняется бесконечно без какой-либо возможности выхода. В результате, программа не может перейти к следующим инструкциям или обработать другие события.

Здесь тебе понадобится модифицировать функцию `main()` следующим образом:

```py
def main():
    global btn3
    
    stop_key = Butik # Получение назначенной кнопки остановки
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed(stop_key): # Проверка, нажата ли кнопка остановки
            break
        click()
```

В этом варианте кода в цикле `while True` будет выполнена проверка на каждой итерации для определения нажатия кнопки остановки. Если кнопка остановки нажата, цикл будет прерван с помощью оператора `break`, и программа перейдет к следующим инструкциям.

Также у тебя в коде отсутствует вызов метода `.get()` для получения значения из виджета `txt.` В функции `clicked()` замените `res = txt.get` на `res = txt.get()`, чтобы правильно получить текст из виджета.

**Другая возможная причина зависания программы** может быть вызвана ошибкой в библиотеке `pyautogui`. Твой код использует функцию `click()` из этой библиотеки, которая имитирует щелчок мыши. Если у тебя установлена устаревшая или несовместимая версия `pyautogui`, это может привести к зависанию программы.

Comment: Все сработало, но после нескольких секунд работы кликера он все равно зависает и не отвисает

Comment: ну ты мои изменение поставь в свой вопрос @FainLight